# Infrared Spectroscopy of N2O

Tags: analytical-chemistry, symmetry, ir-spectroscopy

[image]

Would you be able to identify the stretch and bend in the spectrum? I can not find much information about the $\ce{N2O}$.It's solved, does anyone know the symmetry of these vibrations?

Comment: OCO has a different symmetry than NNO, which should be $C_{\infty v}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what flex and link voltage are; however, here's the rest of it as per [this site at UCLA](http://www2.ess.ucla.edu/~schauble/MoleculeHTML/N2O_html/N2O_page.html) and [this homework solution key from Illinois State](https://about.illinoisstate.edu/standard/Documents/CHE%20362/Homework/362ps5solns.pdf):

The $\ce{N-N}$ stretch is at $\pu{2200 cm-1}$, the $\ce{N-O}$ stretch is at $\pu{1290 cm-1}$, and the doubly-degenerate $\ce{N-N-O}$ bend is at $\pu{590 cm-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

As a general approach there are $3N-6$ normal mode vibrations and $3N-5$ for a linear molecule with *N* atoms, so for N$_2$O there are 4 modes, but some may be degenerate. Next look for overtones, in your spectrum there are lines at  approx 1300 and approx 2600 so these are likely from the same mode. Finally the asymmetric stretch usually has a higher frequency than a symmetric stretch and  bends the the lowest frequency. This will work with a bit of intuition for small molecules but far less so for bigger ones where there are many modes with similar frequencies.

In your case there are lines at $\approx 600, 1300$ and $2200$.  The highest frequency is the motion where the N-N bond compresses and at the same time the NO stretches, i.e. the asymmetric stretch. The symmetric stretch, 1300, is when the N-N bond stretches and so does the N-O, and the bend is doubly degenerate as it can occur in the xz plane and the yz plane if z is the internuclear axis.